# How do you layer ShapeSource components in Mapbox

Tags: react-native, mapbox

Here is the basic look of my Map

```
<MapWrapper />
    <AlertLayer />
    {!!workPackId && (
      <AssetScopeLayer />
    )}
</MapWrapper>
```

Inside both are various `<ShapeSource />`, `<CircleLayer />`, and `<SymbolLayer />`.
That gives me this on the map. [image]

The red dot is the `<AlertLayer />` but it falls underneath the `<AssetScopeLayer />`. Either way I order it it is always underneath.

How can I make the red dot always on top?

Thanks